# How to save an object with array of arrays to backendless with javascript

Tags: javascript, backendless

I am super new in backendless and I am trying to save an object to my backendless table.

I have this following object

```
object = {
    name: something,
    path: locationArray,
    timestamp: timeArray,
    distance: totalDistance,
    photo: imageData
};
```

locationArray is structured like this

```
[[lon,lat],[lon, lat], [lon,lat]].
```

How could i save this to backendless? can i save this whole object in one table? I found difficulty saving an array to backendless. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save arrays as properties of objects in Backendless. For this particular use-case, you could store your locations as `GeoPoint` objects and then create a relation between your object these geopoints.